# I am installing Windows XP SP2 and getting the error below. What is it?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate. I want to have Windows XP installed on my HP Compaq NC6400 laptop but this is the error it gives to me:

> stop: C0000221 unknown Hard Error
>
> \systemroot\system32\ntdll.dll

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you dual booting or is this a new installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Knowledge Base Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314474), that stop-code has two meanings:

- The specified file is corrupted
- An installed driver is incompatible with the hardware

So, did you install any drivers? If yes, then you might wanna try the drivers which are [listed in this blog](http://laptop-driver.blogspot.com/2010/04/hp-compaq-nc6400-windows-xp-driver.html), a reinstallation might be required. If you didn't install anything and this appeared at the first boot, then you've got a problem. Try to get a hold of an Windows XP SP3 CD and try again.